# How to copy the string into the array of strings with strcpy?

Tags: c, string, malloc, strcpy

I'm trying to copy a string into an array of strings, but it doesn't work. I know it is a problem due to memory allocation but I don't see how I could make it work as STRING_LENGTH is a constant.

```
#define NUMBER_OF_STRINGS 3
#define STRING_LENGTH 255
char message_ecran[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH];

int i;
char texte3[] = "CVC";
char texte7[] = "iiiiiiiii";

for (i=0;i<=NUMBER_OF_STRINGS;i++)
{
    strcpy(message_ecran[i], texte7);
}
strcpy(message_ecran[0], texte3);
```

Values of message_ecran after the code:

```
"CVC"
null
"iiiiiiiii"
```

expected values

```
"CVC"    
"iiiiiiiii"
"iiiiiiiii"
```

Comment: it doesnt't work => cf edit

Comment: How are you checking the values of `message_ecran`?

Comment: Also, you should not edit the question in response to corrections provided in answers. This makes it confusing for anyone coming to the question later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that you run past the end of `message_ecran` in the following loop:

```
for (i=0;i<=NUMBER_OF_STRINGS;i++)
```

Since `message_ecran[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS]` is out of bounds, attempting to `strcpy()` into it results in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**edit** With regards to your edit, I can't reproduce the problem. When I add the following to your latest code:

```
for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++) {
  printf("%d:[%s]\n", i, message_ecran[i]);
}
```

it prints out

```
0:[CVC]
1:[iiiiiiiii]
2:[iiiiiiiii]
```

Comment: for (i=0;i<=NUMBER_OF_STRINGS;i++) will this be OK?

Comment: the problem isn't with the for loop, but with the strcpy outside of the loop. The copy outside of the loop puts message_ecran[1] to null

Comment: @edi9999: It's bad form to change the question in response to the answers. Instead of helping future users of the site, it just confuses everyone. In any event, I can't reproduce the latest problem you're reporting.

Answer (score 2):

The code has undefined behaviour as it accessing beyond the bounds of the array at this line:

```
for (i=0;i<=NUMBER_OF_STRINGS;i++)
```

as array indexes are zero-based, and run from `0` to `N - 1` where `N` is the number of elements in the array. This means the valid array indexes for `message_ecran` are `0` and `1` only, but `2` will be used as an index in the `for` loop. Change to:

```
for (i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_STRINGS;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides you can start your loop from 1 ie

```
for (i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++)
```

since you are later assigning 'texte3' at the zeroth location.